# Why are exceptions not being added to signatures?

Tags: java, android

I have been looking through major Android SDK's (Facebook, Google+, and even Android). What I have noticed is that exceptions never seem to be included in method signatures. Instead what I see is that Exceptions are thrown, but usually only listed in the docs (if you are lucky).

What is up with this practice? Is there some manifesto declaring exceptions in method signatures evil?

Examples:
From `android.database.AbstractCursor`

> void checkPosition()
>
> This function throws
>    CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException if the cursor position is out of
>   bounds.

Why this and not

```
void checkPosition() throws CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I prefer the latter since you can set up your IDE/compiler to actually warn you instead of just praying to the bytecode that the docs mention what is acutally being thrown.

Comment: There's a lot of disagreement in the java world over whether to use checked or unchecked exceptions.  Welcome to the debate. :p see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: Isn't this question, in fact, mostly opinion based ?

Comment: @dystroy Partly. It depends on whether the OP knows or not that RuntimeExceptions do not need to be declared, as opposed to checked Exceptions. If yes, then he's asking about our opinion on whether to declare RuntimeExceptions or not.

Comment: @Joffrey Due to the *I prefer the later* I think he knows it.

Comment: @dystroy Very true, indeed. The question might need rewording then.

Answer (score 6):

It's because CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException is a RuntimeException.  It is not a checked exception.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: This is why you have the choice to include it, not why it should or shouldn't be there.

Comment: It is not standard practice to declare thrown RuntimeException types.  They are truly exceptional and you should be defensively writing code to protect yourself from them.  As @azurefrog said, "Welcome to the debate".

Comment: For what little this is worth to you, I tend to prefer checked exceptions as well.  :-)

Comment: The debate @azurefrog talks about is whether or not to use checked or runtime exception, not about declaring RuntimeExceptions in the signature.

Comment: I'm unsure, but I think the OP knows that RuntimeException don't *have to* be added in the signature. I believe he's asking whether it should be done or not.

Comment: At the end of the day every method throws RuntimeExceptions already so there is no point in adding a throws declaration for every potential RuntimeException.  Partly because there is no way to know just what runtime issues may arise.  Maybe you'll run out of memory.  Maybe the thread will get terminated.  Do you really want to see those added as declared exceptions on every java method?  It is the fault of the API developer for not documenting unchecked exceptions properly.

Comment: Here starts the debate ;) but I mostly agree with you, I wouldn't declare all of those. I usually declare the ones I personally throw in the code of the method, if it makes sense to document it.

Comment: What if those aren't thrown there though?  They could have been thrown by another library being used under the hood... In any case, I admit I was being a little outrageous to make a point.

Comment: That's what I meant by *the ones I personally throw in the code of the method*. It is often not the case that a RuntimeException needs documentation anyway.

Comment: My point was that if they are thrown by a 3rd party lib then the OP still has the same problem.

Comment: Alright, then I think your point here better answers the OP than your current answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your precise example, this is informative.

This exception can only be thrown in case of a severe bug in the calling code, so there's no point in writing a `try/catch` for that runtime exception which should not happen in production and there's no point in cluttering the signature.

Comment: Declaring it in the signature doesn't make it a checked exception, does it?

Comment: @Joffrey That's correct, and some devs put runtime exceptions in the method signature as a way of documenting it, even though the user of that method need not actually try/catch for it.

Comment: @azurefrog That's what I'm talking about. I'm one of those developers ;) Using a checked or runtime exception is another debate.

Comment: The checked/unchecked, declare/don't declare arguments today remind me of the vi/emacs wars of yore.

Comment: @azurefrog Well, emacs + coffee, and you have everything =)

Comment: Doesn't emacs make your coffee ?

Comment: I *still* use vim.  /holywar

Comment: @dystroy Indeed: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CoffeeMode I used to hear "emacs does everything but making coffee", I guess it's not up-to-date...